# Show selected option in HTML Select menu after page has been reloaded in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, forms, html-select

I'm building a non-javascript version of a website, as there are a number of customers who don't have javascript enabled. On this site, the customer selects what country they will be visiting and then displays the data related to that country accordingly.

I've managed to get this to work. They use a HTML drop down menu to select the country, click on Submit, and the page reloads with the data related to the selected country. However, it does not change the country displayed in the HTML drop down menu, so when the page reloads it reverts back to "Select A Country".

What I would like to have happen is that if you clicked on United Kingdom from the drop down box for example, when the page reloads the drop down should display United Kingdom.

Here is the code I am currently using for the view file:

```
<form name="countryselect" action="/selected-country/" method="post">
    <select id="country-list" name="countryselected">
        <?php foreach($countries as $coun) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $coun['Tariff']['countryslug']; ?>"><?php echo $coun['Tariff']['countryname']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </select>
</form>
```

And in my controller file I am using this:

```
$countries = $this->Tariff->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Tariff.gsmid' => '1')));
$this->set('countries', $countries); 

if (!isset($_POST['countryselected'])) {

} else {

    $countryselect = $_POST['countryselected'];

    $tarcounselect = $this->Tariff->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Tariff.countryslug' => $countryselect)));
            $this->set('tarcounselect', $tarcounselect); 
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I guess you will need to use session to store their selection in something like $_SESSION['selectedCountry'] and when you redirect you will see if it is not empty then the selected will be equal to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Cake, you should not build the form and the select manually but use the Cake FormHelper instead. It will then keep the selected country automatically:

Controller:

```
$this->set('countries', $this->Tariff->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Tariff.gsmid' => '1'), 'fields' => array('countryslug', 'countryname'))));
```

View:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->select('Tariff.countryslug', $countries);
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
?>
```

And then to retrieve the selected country in the controller:

```
if($this->request->is('post'))
{
  $countryslug = $this->request->data['Tariff']['countryslug'];

}
```

Comment: You accepted my answer before I edited it to add the way to retrieve the selected country :-)

Comment: This is just the last block of code that was missing. It shows you how to get the posted value the Cake way. I did not modify the first two blocks of code.